# How do you get free garages with Rockstar Social Club?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

I know you get a free garage with the Rockstar Social Club and so I signed up and linked it with my Xbox Live account but haven't received the free garages.

Comment: Give it time. Right now the servers are under stress. I used the Social Club to get the Lifeinvader coupons and it took a couple days for the game to register them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you get the garage if you pre-ordered the collectors edition, but you still get the free car that looks like the GT-R and that car is pretty fast.

Comment: Yall are talking about the garage on single player he's talking about the free garage you should get when you sign up for the social network. Its on the tips for online play says you'll receive one online for signing up. I recieved a free sawed off shotgun but dont know wheres the garage

Answer (score 2):

I Just got one free you need to "buy" property. Look on your phone and scroll down to get free garage.

Answer (score -2):

Use the phone to go to the real estate website and scroll down to the bottom. You can purchase the one called "FREE GARAGE".